# execution of cmd file does not works in my PHP

Tags: php, cmd

I try to execute cmd from php code

the command is working when i run it from cmd directly.but from php, does not work.
I try 3 statement and they does not works:

```
    //1-
exec("C:\inetpub\wwwroot\webclient\db\nucleotide\blastdbcmd.exe -db nr -entry all -outfmt "%g %T" -out $text_files_path/NewSeq_$OldDatabaseFile$NewDatabaseFile.txt");


    //2-
exec("cd C:\inetpub\wwwroot\webclient\db\nucleotide && blastdbcmd.exe -db nr -entry all -outfmt \"%g %T\" -out $text_files_path/NewSeq_$OldDatabaseFile$NewDatabaseFile.txt");

    //3-
exec("C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe /c \"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\webclient\db\nucleotide\blastdbcmd.exe -entry $gi -db $DatabaseName -outfmt %f -out $text_files_path\NewSeq_$OldDatabaseFile$NewDatabaseFile.txt\" 2>&1");
```

NewSeq_$OldDatabaseFile$NewDatabaseFile.txt not generated. It seems that the command not executed!

I also try shell_exec but, it does not works.
also I execute bash in the same php file and it is successfully executed which means that shell_exec is not disabled in php.ini

What can I do?

Thanks.

Comment: What errors do you get? Check your logs? Permissions correct?

Comment: @j08691 no error. but, no file in the folder. I have some statement before the exec statement which generate file. that file is created but, the file for exec is not created.

Comment: @milan kyada not work

Comment: @j08691 where can I check the log?

Comment: php has a setting in php.ini file called [disable_functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.disable-functions). you can check it with `var_dump(ini_get('disable_functions'));` if exec is listed there, it is disabled, you need to remove it in php.ini. does it help?

Comment: @Zimmi I dont have php.ini in my computer